# FlatList locks PanResponder items inside

Tags: react-native, draggable, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList that contains a bunch of draggable elements using PanResponder. The elements drag just fine and don't have any issues other than them being "locked" to the area the FlatList is. The FlatList only is about a third of the screen width and I want them to be able to drag these elements out of this third and to the other two thirds but I can't seem to go outside the FlatList with them. If I remove the FlatList everything works how I want, other than being able to scroll through the items.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something in terms of why they are locked inside the FlatList or if there is a different approach that would be better. Any ideas on how to allow these elements to be dragged outside the FlatList would be appreciated.

---

Main Render

```
    <View style={{padding: 10, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
       <FlatList 
            numColumns={2}
            data={this.props.fixtures}
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            renderItem={(item) =>this.renderFixture(item)}
        />
    </View>
```

---

renderItem function

```
    renderFixture = (item) => {
        let i = item.item;
        return <View style={{padding: 5, marginBottom: 10}}>
                    <DragDropSidebar onDrop={this.props.onDrop} fixtureName={i.key} imgUrl={i.url} height={i.height} width={i.width}>
                        <FastImage style={{borderRadius: 5}} source={{uri: i.url}} style={{width: 150, height: 150}}/>
                    </DragDropSidebar>
                <Text style={{color: "white", padding: 5}}>{i.name}</Text>
        </View>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to the problem was actually very simple. I didn't realize that the default overflow value changes on a FlatList. Setting my overflow value to visible on the FlatList solved my issue.